# imaginary number function that passes through certain points

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to figure out how to create a function that accepts as input an imaginary number, and outputs a real number between $0$ and $1$.
Specifically, The function that satisfies
$$
f\left ( a+bi \right ) =  c + 0i
$$where$$
f\left ( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}\;i \right ) = 1
$$and$$
f\left ( 1 + 0i \right ) = 0
$$

I do not have any real experience with imaginary numbers, and would appreciate even a tip on how to start approaching this.

Comment: There are many possible such functions. For one example, $f(z) = \sin^2(3 \arg(z) / 2)\,$.

Comment: Your example accepts a complex number, not a pure imaginary.  We can just add Otherwise $f(a+bi)=2000$ to your second and third lines and have a well defined function that meets your requirements.  What more do you want, so we have a better specification?

Comment: @RossMillikan : OP said "imaginary" but his example clearly shows he means "complex"

Comment: @dxiv : You need to be a little careful since you haven't specified a function (which branch? and worse, what is $\arg(0)$?)

Comment: @MPW It becomes a function if the principal value of $\arg$ is used, and some value is assigned to $f(0)$.

Comment: so, you have imaginary experience with imaginary numbers?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you want the function to do? In english? we have f(1) = 0. And  $f(\sqrt[3](-1)= \frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt 3} 2) = 1$.  Why do you want those answers for those input?  What should f(0) be?  What should f(i) be?  We can make up uncountably many such functions.  But it sounds like you have something specific in mind.

Comment: So, you are correct that I mean that the input to the function should be a complex number. I do have something specific in mind, imagine the complex plain as an input, and the output must be a real number. This is one example, I have another where the inputs map to the reversed outputs.

Comment: But, I do not know complex numbers well enough to form a general equation. For example if I have two points on a plain, I can make a function that will put a line through those two points. What I don't know is how to make a function that takes two complex points and maps them to two specific real numbers. I do not care about the shape of the function, nore does the output have to be on [0:1]

Comment: "I do have something specific in mind, imagine the complex plain as an input, and the output must be a real number. "  That is too broad to be of any use whatsoever.  The function f(1/2 + i root(3)/2) = 1, and f(z) = 0 for all other complex numbers does what you want.  If you want your function to act a certain way you must *tell* us what you want it do.  Having two values is not enough.  Is the function linear?  Is is it continuous?  Does it have any features at all?  Your question is unanswerable right now.

Comment: well, it's ok.  Turns out I was able to find the answer to my question elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was looking for was [Isomorphism between Roots of Unity under Multiplication and Integers under Modulo Addition](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Isomorphism_between_Roots_of_Unity_under_Multiplication_and_Integers_under_Modulo_Addition).  Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 1):

From wolfram: "A function is a relation that uniquely associates members of one set with members of another set."

All that means is you wish to have a relation between $\mathbb C$ the set of all complex numbers to the real interval $[0,1]$.  (BTW, you meant "complex"; not imaginary. a complex number is of the form $a + bi$ which is a combination of real and imaginary.  An imaginary number of the form $0 + bi$ which is "purely" imaginary.  A real number is of the form $a + i0$ which is "purely" real.)

You want $f(1) = f(1 + i0) = 0$ and you want $f(\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt 3}2) = 1$.

The remaining values can be *anything*.  You could say: $f$ is the function so that $f(1) =0$ and $f(\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt 3}2) = 1$ and $f(z) = 0$ for all other $z$.  That is perfectly acceptable and a legitimate and well-defined function.

Or we could have $f(0+ 0i) = .25$; $f(a+bi) = 0$ if $b=0;a ne 0$; $f(a+bi) = .75$ if $a=0; b\ne 0$; $f(a+bi) = 1$ if $a\ne 0; b\ne 0$.

Or you can have anything you want.

I suspect you have more in mind than just that.  You say $f(a+bi ) = c$.  But what is the relationship between $a, b$ and $c$?

You chose the number $z=\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt{3}}2$ which is an interesting number because $z^2 = (\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt{3}}2)(\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt{3}}2) = \frac 14 + i\frac {\sqrt{3}}2 - \frac 34= -\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt{3}}2$.  And so $z^3 = (-\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt{3}}2)(\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt{3}}2)= (\frac {\sqrt{3}}2i)^2 - (\frac 12)^2 = -\frac 34 - \frac 14 = -1$.  So $z$ is one of the cube roots of $-1$.

I suspect that has something to do with what you want the function to do but I don't know what.

Comment: You are correct that I chose those numbers very intentionally. They form a 3-cycle. And those three Numbers are the only ones I care about (for now). But, you are mistaken that the output must fall on [0:1]. I am curious about how to force the complex input to a specific real output, for two points, then I'd imagine 3, for the 3 cycle.

Comment: so what I'm asking, really, is methods that can produce this result. When I think about how I might product this myself, I think of putting the output on a third axis, and drawing a line between the points I want. But, I don't really know how that would work. I don't really want to break apart the input into a and b if possible.

Comment: "you are mistaken that the output must fall on [0:1]"  ????  You said, and I quote "and outputs a real number between 0 and 1".  "I chose those numbers very intentionally. They form a 3-cycle... I am curious about how to force the complex input to a specific real output, for two points, then I'd imagine 3, for the 3 cycle".  That's utterly incomprehensible.  No-one can answer this question if you don't actually specify what the question means.

Comment: And *what* three points?  You gave f(1) = 0 and f(1/2 + i root(3)/2) = 1.  What's the third point?  f(a,b) = c is not a specified point.

Comment: " really, is methods that can produce this result."  Okay.  One method.  You declare that f(1) = 0 and f(1/2 + i sqrt(3)/2) = 1.  THen you declare whatever you effing want to declare for all the other values.  You seem to be deliberately missing the point that a function can be *ANY* mapping.  *ANYTHING* you want.  There is *NO* possible way this question can have any answer. Here's one that does what you want f(a+bi =0 if $a>b$ and f(a + bi)=1 if $a \le b$.  Here's another.  f(a+bi) = 1 if $(a+bi)^3 < 0$ and f(a+bi) = 0 if $(a+bi)^3 \ge 0$ and $f(a+bi) = .5$ if $(a+bi)^3 \not \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I did say that. If you can't tell the third point is -1/2 -sqrt(3)i/2 what I mean is that my every point needs to be within [0:1] just those two points. Every other input can may to anything.  I didn't mean to upset you. I was on my phone when replying, and in a hurry. Clarity is not strong suit.

Comment: Anyway, I do understand what a function is. But, I cannot simply define the points, because that would have to be an axiomatic definition. If I want a line that passes through two points in Euclidean space, I can use y=mx+b and transformations on that equation to pass the line through two points.  How does this work if x is complex, and y is not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60670/discussion-between-vonwoodson-and-fleablood).

Answer (score 0):

Given distinct complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$, the function $f:\mathbb C\to[0,1]$ given by $$f(z)=\left(\left|\frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1}\right|\vee0\right)\wedge1$$
does the job, where "$\vee$" is the "$\max$" operator and "$\wedge$" is the "$\min$" operator (here, you have $z_1=1$ and $z_2=\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$).

This function takes value in $[0,1]$ and has $f(z_1)=0$, $f(z_2)=1$.

Of course, there are many functions with the properties you desire.